# Reading from a txt file with rows and columns

Tags: android

I have some txt files that contain values arranged like this :

```
 Aaaaa      0.55     2
 bbb        2.1      0.25
 cccccc     71       21
 .....      ...      ...
```

I want to take each column and put it inside a separate `String[]` so i can reference for example `column1`,`row1` with for example `product[0]`,`column2` `row1` with `quantity[0]` and `column3` `row1` with `price[0]` and so on.

How can i read the file and store them in `Strings[]`?
Thanks and have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by reading the whole file first and create a 2d array ( or an array of object).

hints:

1. read the file line by line
2. for each line get the different values separated by blank spaces.
3. for each line put every element in a 2d Array or an array of object

**Update**

to get the strings separated by spaces you can use

```
String str = "Aaaaa      0.55     2";
String[] tokens = str.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: How can i get the different values separated by blank spaces ?

Comment: And how can i make it put every split of the string into a different string ? Like i said in my initial post : put the column 1 in a string[] ,column 2 in another string[] so i can the reference it for example : column1[2] will give me the third product on the first column

Comment: if you use a 2d array just for each row use the str.split

Comment: I think you better start coding... post the code if you have further problem.. ifyou implement the steps prpoerly you should have solved it